# Get average for everyday - SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a field of Timestamp and I want to find the average hours spent every day.

Lets say:

```
created: 2020-01-01 23:15:44
Resolved: 2020-01-04 12:00:00
```

I need my output to be:

```
Date         Mins
2020-01-01   45
2020-01-02   1440
2020-01-03   1440
2020-01-04   720
```

I have built a calendar table, but I'm not sure how to use it.

Comment: Just to lead my answer in the correct way: your table has two fields with timestamps and you want to get the interval between, group them by date and then get the average of it?

Comment: @procra, Yes , exactly!

Comment: Ok so I reworked my answer as it didnt detect durations that exceed one day or that cross a date before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can join to your calendar table and calculate the time different for beginning and ending of the date range.

```
select c.[date] as [Date], 
       case when c.[date] = convert(date, t.created) 
            then datediff(minute, t.created, dateadd(day, 1, c.[date]))
            when c.[date] = convert(date, t.resolved) 
            then datediff(minute, c.[date], t.resolved)
            else 1440
            end AS [Mins]
from   yourtable t
       inner join calendar c on  c.[date] >= convert(date, t.created)
                             and c.[date] <= convert(date, t.resolved)
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b2feaec4036afe4c3f3070c9a725e2c6)

If you need the average, just use `GROUP BY` and `AVG()` accordingly

Answer (score 1):

Let `tickets` be your table and `creation_timestamp` as `resolve_timestamp` are your described fields. All in all we have three steps to compute:

- calculate the interval between two timestamps of one row
- group the intervals by day
- for each day, calculate the average interval

  ```
    SELECT
        t.date,

        /*Convert the interval of this function into a number*/
        extract(

            /*calculate the intervals here and draw the average*/
            day from AVG(t.resolve_timestamp - t.creation_timestamp)* 1440 + 
            hour from AVG(t.resolve_timestamp - t.creation_timestamp) * 60 +
            minute from AVG(t.resolve_timestamp - t.creation_timestamp)

        ) AS avg_duration_in_minutes

        FROM tickets t

    /*do that distinctly for every t.date*/
    GROUP BY t.date
    ORDER BY t.date DESC;
  ```

**NOTE:** This is a syntax you would use on an Oracle DB. There might be differences to SQL Server

Comment: This is not related to SQL Server at all.  How does such an answer get an upvote?

Comment: @GordonLinoff You're right I didn't focus on SQL Server environment (to be honest I have totally overlooked that tag). I could try to look up how to set this up properly for SQL server but this might take time others might be faster writing a better answer than me ;)

Comment: . . Your answer may be fine and people make such mistakes all the time -- and I'm not suggesting that anyone downvote it (although you might want to delete it or add a note indicating what database this is actually for).  I just find the upvote very curious.

Answer (score 1):

Try this **RECURSIVE CTE**

```
 DECLARE @CreateDate DateTime='2020-01-01 23:15:44',
 @EndDate DATETIME='2020-01-04 12:00:00'

;WITH sample AS (
  SELECT @CreateDate  AS StartDate
  UNION ALL
  SELECT DATEADD(dd, 1, StartDate)
  FROM sample s
  WHERE DATEADD(dd, 1, StartDate) <= DATEADD(dd, 1,@EndDate)
  )

SELECT CAST(StartDate as date),case when StartDate=@CreateDate then 
DATEDIFF(MI,StartDate,DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, StartDate), '23:59:59'))+1
else DATEDIFF(MI,CAST(StartDate as date),DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, StartDate), 
'23:59:59'))+1 end
 FROM sample
```